# Visual Studio - Renaming and compiler directives

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

So when I use the visual studio rename option (CTRL-R CTRL-R), it works great, unless I have code that is hidden by a compiler directive...

For example:

```
#if IOS_BUILD
SomeClass c = new SomeClass();
#endif
```

Now, if I go to SomeClass and try to rename it (change class name), but IOS_BUILD is false (only becomes true in the builder), then it won't rename the SomeClass instance inside the #if statement.

Then when my builder tries to build, setting IOS_BUILD to true, it will tell fail due to SomeClass not existing...

Ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: In a small project, it could work to do search/replace instead of renaming, but that's kinda bad because it's not guaranteed to get all the references.
How about abolishing #if statements in favour of `System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute`?

Comment: Good idea! I wasn't familiar with that, will definitely use it in the future. If you make this an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @DhavalPatel - almost, Unity3d